# Get id of div with onclick function

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a onclick even on a div as follow

```js
function copyToClipboard(e) {
  var textBox = document.getElementById(e.id);
  console.log(textBox);
  textBox.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```html
<div class="form-inline m-2">

  <input type="text" class="form-inline" name="myvalue" id="{{ p.id }}" value="https://diccionarioespañol.com/significado/{{ p.nombre|lower }}/" readonly />
  <button onclick="copyToClipboard(this)"></button>

</div>
```

The issue is I'm unable to get the `textBox` to show the input data.  Instead it shows null.  So how do I get the id from the div or the url value sent to the clipboard

Comment: you didn't provide id to button. Which element id do you want to get on button click

Comment: @DanielWilliams that was correct if you want to post answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your button is not referencing the input. Try this.

```js
function copyToClipboard(theId) {
  var textBox = document.getElementById(theId);
  console.log(textBox);
  textBox.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```html
<div class="form-inline m-2">

  <input type="text" class="form-inline" name="myvalue" id="{{ p.id }}" value="https://diccionarioespañol.com/significado/{{ p.nombre|lower }}/" readonly />
  <button onclick="copyToClipboard('{{ p.id }}')"></button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are depending on the click event, you can check the parent from which you can find the input node.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
function copyToClipboard(e) {
  const input = Array.from(e.target.parentNode.children).find(node => node.nodeName === "INPUT");
  console.log(input.id);
  var textBox = document.getElementById(input.id);
  console.log(textBox);
  textBox.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```html
<div class="form-inline m-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-inline" name="myvalue" id="p.id"
    value="https://diccionarioespañol.com/significado/{{ p.nombre|lower }}/" readonly />
  <button onclick="copyToClipboard(event)"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use closest to get the parent then use the parent to query the input and then get the event targets id. I however did not use the `onclick` attribute. I added a selector to the button and used `addEventListsner()` with that selector instead passing the function as a callback into the listener.

```js
function copyToClipboard(e) {
  const target = e.target.closest('.form-inline').querySelector('input');
  var textBox = document.getElementById(target.id);
  console.log(target);
  textBox.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', copyToClipboard)
```

```html
<div class="form-inline m-2">

  <input type="text" class="form-inline" name="myvalue" id="{{ p.id }}" value="https://diccionarioespañol.com/significado/{{ p.nombre|lower }}/" readonly />
  <button id="button"></button>

</div>
```